# Woo API REST : product variation price is read-only?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I see `price    string  Current variation price. [read-only]` on [this](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-variations) documentation (official api rest doc from WooCommerce).

Does it mean that it's impossible to make an app to update a product variation price ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, i found this [example](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#update-a-product-variation) : `PUT /wp-json/wc/v3/products/<product_id>/variations/<id>`

So in javascript we could do :

```js
const data = {
  regular_price: "10.00"
};

WooCommerce.put("products/22/variations/733", data)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

And the JSON API Response :

```
{
  "id": 733,
  "date_created": "2017-03-23T00:53:11",
  "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:53:11",
  "date_modified": "2017-03-23T00:53:11",
  "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:53:11",
  "description": "",
  "permalink": "https://example.com/product/ship-your-idea/?attribute_pa_color=green",
  "sku": "",
  "price": "10.00",
  "regular_price": "10.00",
  "sale_price": "",
  ...
}
```

I'll do some test, but i think it's possible to update a product variation price with WooCommerce API/REST.

Comment: Side note: In your app you probably won't have the `WooCommerce` JS variable. So be sure to check the [authentication](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys) part in the REST API doc as well

Comment: Thank you @kero for the tips